# JavaScript MinValue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need find the minimum value from a two-dimensional array.
But something goes wrong, someone can explain me please?

```js
let array = [
  [20, 34, 2],
  [9, 12, 18],
  [3, 4, 5]
];


let str = array.join(",");
console.log(str);

let array_2 = str.split(",");
console.log(array_2);


let minValue = array_2[0];
for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
    if (array_2[i] < minValue) {
      minValue = array_2[i];
    }
}
console.log(minValue);
```

[image]

Comment: `"12"` is less than `"2"`, in Javascript. Because these are Strings, and `"1"` comes before `"2"` in alphabetical order. You need to convert these Strings to Numbers.

Comment: why joining to a string?

Comment: He does not know about [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Thanks a lot of your answer description! Its helps me lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the strings to numbers so that numerical comparison is used instead of lexicographical comparison.

```js
let array = [
  [20, 34, 2],
  [9, 12, 18],
  [3, 4, 5]
];


let str = array.join(",");
console.log(str);

let array_2 = str.split(",").map(Number);//convert to number
console.log(array_2);


let minValue = array_2[0];
for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
    if (array_2[i] < minValue) {
      minValue = array_2[i];
    }
}
console.log(minValue);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) on the original array so that you do not need to `join` and `split`.

```js
let array = [
  [20, 34, 2],
  [9, 12, 18],
  [3, 4, 5]
];
let array_2 = array.flat();
console.log(array_2);
let minValue = array_2[0];
for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
    if (array_2[i] < minValue) {
      minValue = array_2[i];
    }
}
console.log(minValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is to flatten the array with [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and get the minimum with [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) by spreading the values ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

```js
let array = [[20, 34, 2], [9, 12, 18], [3, 4, 5]];

console.log(Math.min(...array.flat()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Strings to **Number** before the comparison

```
 let array = [
  [20, 34, 2],
  [9, 12, 18],
  [3, 4, 5]
];


let str = array.join(",");
console.log(str);
//here you convert to number
let array_2 = str.split(",").map(Number);
console.log(array_2);
```

Initialize minValue with the **highest** possible value

you should use **Number.MAX_VALUE**;

```
let minValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;
```

**All together**

```js
let array = [
    [20, 34, 2],
    [9, 12, 18],
    [3, 4, 5]
  ];
  
  let str = array.join(",");
  console.log(str);
  
  let array_2 = str.split(",").map(Number);
  console.log(array_2);
  
  
  let minValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
      if (array_2[i] < minValue) {
        minValue = array_2[i];
      }
  }
  console.log(minValue);
```